# Cypress | Cant change variable inside each loop

Tags: variables, integer, each, cypress, var

OK, So, I have this code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add ('MethodName', (argument) => {

    var Fails = 0

    cy.get('anything').each(Id => {
        if (blablabla) {
        Fails += 1
            cy.log("Inside the each: " + Fails) //prints 1
    }
    })
    cy.log("Outside the each: " + Fails) //prints 0
 
});
```

I want to test each item and if a condition is wrong, I want to add 1 to the variable "Fails".

Then, in the end, if Fails is 0, then there are no errors, and I want it to log the message "NO FAILS". The problem is , even if the variable changes to 1 inside the EACH, when its outside, it comes back to 0.

This is so frustrating to me, because Im used to write C# code and in C#, that would work, since the declaration of the variable is outside the each.

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript runs asynchronously which means that your codes doesn't run in sequence. So what's happening in your case is `Outside the each:` is executing first and after that `Inside the each:` is being executed. To make sure that *Outside each* runs after *inside each*, you have to use `then()`.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('MethodName', (argument) => {
   var Fails = 0
   cy.get('anything').each(Id => {
      if (blablabla) {
         Fails += 1
         cy.log("Inside the each: " + Fails)
      }
   }).then(() => {
      cy.log("Outside the each: " + Fails)
   })
})
```

Comment: I see it! Thank you very much!